# PDF Viewer with possibility to add custom tools/ pass selected data in pdf to python script

Tags: python, pdf, web, sdk

**Summarize the problem**

PDF SDK allowing to add custom tool - i.e. select data (text or table) in PDF and pass to custom python script. Then provide user with feedback based on outcome of analysis by python script

**Describe what you've tried:**

I tested Apryse webviewer SDK, PSPDFkit SDK, pdfrest - but those don't allow for table extraction using python script.In case of apryse it's possible to select data but, based on their documentation it's not clear how to pass text to python script.

Could you advise on the technology stack to implement pdf webviewer which allows for adding custom tools as described below:

Text Extraction: I need the ability to allow users to select text from a PDF document, extract that selected text, and pass it to a custom Python function for further processing. After the processing, I would need to provide feedback to the users based on outcome of analysis by python script.

Table Extraction: Another aspect of my application involves extracting tables from PDF documents.
Therefore I need webviewer which will allow me to build custom tool for table extraction (python)
These extracted tables would then be passed to a Python script for analysis.

I would appreciate any tools recommendation (PDF SDK suitable for above, and how to solve passing data from PDF SDK into python script)

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: There are tables in pdf, and my python script extracts them into df (i know that in fact in pdf there is no table but I was able to succesfully extract them using pdfplumber). 
I am not looking for simple text extraction package. I need pdf viewer so user can open pdf in it and then select appropriate text for further analysis.

I need pdf viewer to which I can add my own tools, say Tool 1: 'select table' and perform given analysis on it.
Tool 2: select text and perform another analysis. Where analysis will be performed by python script in the background. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: @KJ thanks for response. As written above, I managed to solve the problem with table extraction for my particular type of pdf using python script (pdfplumber package). Now I need GUI which will allow me to implement this python script as a tool in pdf viewer GUI. So user can select tool 'extract table' on given page and do X with it. Where X will be performed by python script. I couldn't find example of such integration in apryse documentation or forum. If you are aware of such, from apryse or other pdf SDK provide please let me know. Thank you.